# Danny's phone in Iron Fist

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-fist

In episode 11 of *Iron Fist* Danny says to Davos after breaking his phone because hand may track them, that he left his phone back at the compound. But he has a phone in the next episode when Bakuto video calls him. Any explanation?

Comment: He bought a new phone?

Comment: Bakuto called on wing's phone I think

Comment: No he takes it out of his pocket and the call was from Ward's phone.if he bought a new phone ward wouldn't have that number, not that soon

Comment: I spotted that It just jumped out at me as a glaring continuity error, nothing more.

Comment: I noticed this plot hole too, but I was actually glad because up to that point, with the way the plot had been going, I would have expected a 15 minute scene where Danny goes into a shop and buys a new phone (Samsung, of course) and picks out a case and says he can't trade in his old one because he left it at the compound of the evil ninja group that's after him. Compared to the tedium of that scene, I was fine with the plot hole.